# Codeigniter 4 Soft Delete Still Deleting DB Record

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, soft-delete

I have a problem with CodeIgniter 4 Soft Delete.
I've set $useSoftDelete = true in the model; but whenever i delete a record, the delete method always purge it from my table.

Here is the code in my model :

```
    // Dates
protected $useTimestamps        = true;
protected $useSoftDelete        = true;
protected $dateFormat           = 'datetime';
protected $createdField         = 'cust_created_at';
protected $updatedField         = 'cust_updated_at';
protected $deletedField         = 'cust_deleted_at';
```

Here is my delete method in my controller :

```
public function delete($id = '')
{
    $customer = $this->customerModel->find($id);
    if (isset($customer)) {
        $this->customerModel->delete($id);
        session()->setFlashdata('success', "Customer $customer->cust_name successfully deleted.");
        return redirect()->to(site_url('customer'));
    } else {
        session()->setFlashdata('errors', ["Cannot find customer ID $id."]);
        return redirect()->to(site_url('customer'));
    }
}
```

Any code I missed?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in
`protected $useSoftDelete        = true;`.
it should be
`protected $useSoftDeletes        = true;`

Ref:
https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html#configuring-your-model

Comment: You are right. I create my model with "php spark make:model" command. It generates $useSoftDelete instead of $useSoftDeletes. Thank you